# How to Compile telegram-cli in windows by cygwin?

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin, telegram

**I have Installed the complete cygwin packages and I have done the steps mentioned in this guide [Link](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/blob/master/README-Cygwin.md) 
The guide is like this:**

...

Then, go to tg directory then generate Makefile.

```
 cd tg
 ./configure
```

We need to patch Makefile and loop.c to compile in cygwin. Download this patch then untar. Then, patch in tg directory.

```
 patch -p1 < telegram-cli-cygwin.patch
```

Then make

After compile is done, telegram-cli.exe will be generated in bin directory.

To run telegram-cli, type

```
 bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub
```

Caution: A binary compiled with Cygwin should be run in Cygwin Terminal.

**I have done the all the steps successfully but when I patch the make file and the loop.c it says:**

```
$ patch -p1 < telegram-cli-cygwin.patch
patching file Makefile
Hunk #1 succeeded at 4 with fuzz 2.
patching file loop.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 383.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 739 with fuzz 2 (offset 105 lines).
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file loop.c.rej
```

**And for the next step when it says 'Then make' I have tried using the command "./configure" I dont know if I am doing this right?
And after executing the command:**

```
bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub
```

**It says :**

```
$ bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub
-bash: bin/telegram-cli: No such file or directory
```

**And It is right because there is no exe file created to be run. I would appreciate Any help.**

Comment: The patching failed. You need to resolve the rejected patches manually first. That is, open `loop.rej.c.` and manually integrate that diff hunk into `loop.c`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kaylum.
For the 'Then make' step I am doing right to use the command './configure' ? I am not very familiar with  unix based commands.

Comment: `configure` doesn't actually do the build. It just prepares the build. I don't know this code in particular. But the general procedure is to run some form of `make` after the `configure`. But the exact command should be contained in the build instructions/README. Likely to be `make all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the patches manually after configure as @kaylum mentioned. It has to be after the configure command because the make file has to patched too and the configure command affects the make file. after that the make or make all command has to executed and the `.exe` file is created.

Comment: As @kaylum mentioned, I patched the files manually after configure. Bu after that when I try `make`, it says no targets specified and no makefile found. The data to be patched was actually in the the `makefile.in `. Now I have patched but No telegram-cli created

Comment: I tried making a copy of makefile.in and renamed it to makefile and ran the make command. `@srcdir@/Makefile.tgl` not found. But that file is right there in the tg directory!